# Ruby on Rails - Arabic text sometimes being encoded, and others not - why and how to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arabic, urlencode, arabic-support

I want to save a wikipedia link that has Arabic characters in it.

In my console I can do

```
> title = "The Broken Wings / الأجنحة المتكسرة"
 => "The Broken Wings / الأجنحة المتكسرة
```

And it returns properly with English and Arabic. But if I try to save a link, it encodes the Arabic characters.

When I try to enter this link : `https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/الأجنحة_المتكسرة`
it changes to `https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%AC%D9%86%D8%AD%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%83%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%A9`

How can I save the link as-is?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by 'console' you mean the Rails console. Ruby (since 2.0) uses UTF-8 as its default character encoding. That means it can natively handle Universal Character Set (aka Unicode) characters. So, when you work with Arabic strings in the Rails console there is no transformation occurring.

However, for URIs (Uniform Resource Identifier -- simplistically the 'path' part of a URL), the standard (RFC3986) says that only US-ASCII and some special characters are allowed. You **can** use other characters to specify a location (what is called an Internationalized Resource Identifier), but only some systems natively understand IRIs. Otherwise, they get translated to a byte encoding called 'Percent-Encoding', which is what you see in the wikipedia URL.

This [introduction](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/) does a more complete job of explaining how multi-lingual web addressing works and how translation between IRIs and URIs works with percent encoding.

Comment: In general, I want to be able to save a string that does not convert the arabic text. Whether the string is a URL or not. By console, I mean the Rails console, but that is just an example - trying to save the URL from a form into the database does the same thing. Any suggestion on how to save a string with arabic text? Thanks!

Comment: Rails 'out of the box' should save/load Unicode strings nicely. I suggest you edit your question with a more specific example of your code and information (version of Rails, which database you use, etc.). That will help people help you better.

Comment: the issue seems to be when arabic is joined without a space into non-arabic script.

Comment: Something like ``'helloالعالمية'``? (Sorry, I don't speak Arabic so hopefully that's not gibberish.)